# Creating a Tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

I have what should be a simple assignment, but after cramming learning what a tree is and how to use one, I'm fried and having trouble fixing the problem. I understand why this program doesn't work, I'm just having trouble finding a solution.

The assignment is to create a tree containing string data. We are given a text file containing strings separated by lines, and we are to create a tree with the data. Each line contains three strings. The left-most string goes into a Node, the middle string goes into the Nodes left child, and the right-most string goes into the Nodes right child. Also, if the left or right string is "null", that means the node has no child on the left or right, respectively.

The text file looks something like this...

```
dog over brown
over red jumped
red The quick 
The null null
```

Resulting tree would be like this:
`Dog` would be the root node, pointing left to `over` and pointing right to `brown`.
`Over` would be pointing left to `red`, and pointing right to `jumped`.
`Red` would be pointing left to `The`, and pointing right to `quick`.

This is my attempt at creating this program:

```
struct Node
{
    string name;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

Node* allocNode(string name) {
    Node *newNode = new Node();
    newNode->name = name;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

Node* Insert(Node* rootPtr, string left, string mid, string right);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Node* rootPtr;
    rootPtr = NULL; //empty tree
    cout << "Specify an input file:\n";
    string filepath;
    cin >> filepath;
    ifstream istream (filepath);
    string line;

    while (getline(istream,line))
    {
        string word[3];
        stringstream ssin(line);
        int i = 0;
        while (ssin.good())
        {
            ssin >> word[i];
            i++;
        }
        string left = word[0];
        string mid = word[1];
        string right = word[2];
        rootPtr = Insert(rootPtr, left, mid, right);
    }


    return 0;
}


Node* Insert(Node* rootPtr, string left, string mid, string right)
{
    rootPtr = allocNode(left);

    if (mid != "null") {
        rootPtr->left = Insert(rootPtr->left,mid);//problem here
    }

    if (right != "null") {
        rootPtr->right = Insert(rootPtr->right, right); //problem here
    }
    return rootPtr;
}
```

To my understanding, the problem comes with the recursion. Specifically when I try to assign the left or right pointer to rootPtr, because I cannot go down the lines in the input file while in recursion and therefore being unable to insert a node. I've tried a few different things, messing with the parameters but I haven't been able to solve it. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Using that example text file, do you expect to get *one* tree, or *four?*

Comment: @Beta I am expected to get one tree. Using the example text file, the resulting tree would be like this:

Comment: @Beta I have updated my original post, as it was unclear.

Comment: Consider teaming up with the asker of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357322/tree-sort-algorithm-skips-certain-values . Two heads are better than one.

Comment: @user4581301 Ha, that is actually probably someone in my class!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Insert` function natures a `Node* rootPtr` parameter but does *nothing* with it, because this pointer is immediately reset to a freshly allocated `Node`:

```
Node* Insert(Node* rootPtr, string left, string mid, string right)
{
    rootPtr = allocNode(left);
    ...
```

Because its freshly allocated, `rootPtr->left` and `rootPtr->right` are both `NULL` -- although that barely matters because they are immediately passed back to `Insert`. If you're not careful you'll have an infinite loop, but its hard to say because your interior calls to `Insert` only have two parameters instead of the required 4 and so they should not compile. You should reexamine what each parameter passed to `Insert` means and how they should be treated.

Comment: Another note: based on a quick count, `Insert(rootPtr->left,mid)` does not have sufficient parameters to satisfy `Node* Insert(Node* rootPtr, string left, string mid, string right)`

Answer (score 0):

You can break the problem down into simpler parts. Suppose you are half-way through the file, the tree is half-complete, and you read a line:

```
dish ran away
```

What must you do? According to the pattern in the example, the node `dish` must already be a leaf in the tree (that is, a node whose `left` and `right` are both null). So you must

1. Find `dish`,

   give it a new left node, `ran` and

   give it a new right node, `away`.

That first step requires a function that searches the tree recursively, looking for a node with a given name, and returns a pointer to that node (null if no such node is in the tree). Steps 2 and 3 are easy after that.

Once that is working, you can iterate through the file without difficulty. Don't forget that you must give special attention to the first node, the root of the tree.